# Navigation not hidding after hover on next element

Tags: jquery, navigation, hover, time-wait

I need a navigation that when I mouse out, waits for 1 sec, and then hide,

I got my code here

http://jsfiddle.net/xR83q/

but it does not work correctly

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Working in FF4.  what browsers are you seeing the issue in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead - change the last 2 lines to:

```
$j('#menu-navegacion-principal > li')
    .bind('mouseenter', navIn)
    .bind('mouseleave', navOut);

$j('#menu-navegacion-principal > li:has(ul)')
    .bind('mouseenter', navInS)
    .bind('mouseleave', navOutS)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I try it and still doesn't fix the hover not to hide on the right time.

Comment: Chrome, and now I find out what was the problem, the line with $("#"+_CancelBtn).hide(); , need it to be $j instead of $, thanks for your time ^^

Comment: No probs.  you should still use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for this particular case though. :)  Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Whats the diference between a "hover" and bind a  "mounseenter or mouseleave"? do I have any benefits?

Comment: The hover event will fire mouseout when a child element is mouseover'd, whereas using mouseenter mouseleave will properly account for children so that events don't mis-bubble and trigger unexpected events.